# Sleep - countable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

So my first assumption is, of course, that you have to say "I had **little sleep**", but so many people say "I had **a little sleep**", and I can't understand why "sleep" becomes **countable** all of a sudden. Is my initial assumption wrong?

Comment: _A little_ and _a few_ are idiomatically opposed to _little_ and _few_; the latter are always negative --  _Little sleep_ means almost none; but _a little sleep_ means more than that. It means enough sleep to feel rested, though still less than usual. So it's not a matter of countability -- it's a matter of whether it's less than enough or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm afraid your assumption is wrong.

*Sleep* can be uncountable, or countable. When countable it means "an occasion when one sleeps or slept or will sleep".

*I had little sleep* and *I had a little sleep* mean very different things; because *little* with an uncountable NP has a negative connotation, and implies "not enough", whereas *little* with a countable NP does not have that implication.

So

> I had little sleep

implies that I didn't sleep long enough, and I am tired, whereas

> I had a little sleep

just says that the time of sleeping was not long, but on the face of it says nothing about whether it was long enough or not.

Actually, though, it does something more, because *little* is a word that is usually used with some emotive connotation (usually positive, though not always). Saying *a little sleep* rather than the more neutral *a short sleep* suggests that the speaker is satisfied with the sleep, and may be minimising the sleep or its importance: possible meanings that occur to me are "I only needed a short sleep, and I'm refreshed" or "I actually slept for quite a while, but I don't want to admit that I needed that".

One use of countable *sleep* that has become quite common recently (and that I guessed your question might be about from the title) is the phrase *(number) more sleeps until (event)!* when talking about something happening in a few days.

**Edit** Ceejay points out another possible meaning, that I missed. *A little* can be a quantifier in its own right, used with uncountables. It doesn't have the negative connotations of *little*. So *a little sleep* could means *sleeping for a short time*, as I indicated above; but it could also mean *a small amount of sleep*. In some cases there will be no effective difference in the meaning, but sometimes these two could have different implications.

Comment: isn't "a little" an adverb here? which means an article is not really connected to the noun, it's connected to the word "little", and you probably have to say "I slept *a little*".. In "I had a little sleep",  "little" is just an adjective, and not the part of an adverb ..am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it an adverb, but you're right, that's another possible meaning, that I missed.

Answer (score -1):

https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/few-a-few-little-a-little;

In India it is taught to the students like, LITTLE, A LITTLE, and THE LITTLE. Similarly, FEW, A FEW, and THE FEW.

As commonly known, 'little' points to uncountable nouns, and 'few' to countable nouns.

When one says, There is little water, it means 'there is (practically) no water'.
There is a little water = There is a small quantity of water.
"The little" is used when little/a little once mentioned is repeated in the same context, like, 'Someone drank the little water left in the jar.'

Similar is the use of 'few' too.

Comment: Yes, but _little_ can also mean _small_. _A little sleep_ here means _a period of sleep_ that was quite short.

Comment: "As commonly known, 'little' points to uncountable nouns" This is false—at least as a general statement. *I ate 3 **little** apples.* *Little* is an adjective that can be applied to any type of noun in the right context.

Comment: @JasonBassford, You may refer to this link: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/how_to_use_adjectives_and_adverbs/index.html, which clearly says that little refers to uncountable nouns. I don't have the courage to say that Purdue is wrong.

Comment: @RamPillai Again, that's specific to a single context. It's *not* specific to other contexts, which have already been pointed out in comments here. Purdue is quite correct in what it says (it's not wrong), but what it says doesn't apply to to *every* situation. If you think it does, then you're misconstruing the explanation.